# Wrong result with PHP function 'mysql_fetch_Assoc'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem with the PHP function 'mysql_fetch_assoc()'

```
public function result ($query) {
    $result = false;
    if (is_resource($this->resourceHandler)) {
        $result = array();
        while ($tempVar = @mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $result[] = $tempVar;
        }
    }else{
        throw new Exception ('Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank vorhanden!');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

When i run this function the array returned should look like this:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [description] => Test
                [date] => 2012-08-09
            )
[1] => Array
            (
                [nummer] => 2
                [beschreibung] => Test2
                [datum] => 2012-08-09
            )
[2] => Array
            (
                [nummer] => 3
                [beschreibung] => test3
                [datum] => 2012-08-10
            )
```

But it looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [description] => Test
                [date] => 2012-08-09
            )
[1] => Array
            (
                [nummer] => 
                [beschreibung] => 
                [datum] => 1970-01-01
            )
[2] => Array
            (
                [nummer] => 3
                [beschreibung] => test3
                [datum] => 2012-08-10
            )
```

The second element of my array is ALWAYS empty. It's regardless which sql-query is used. Does anybody know this problem?

Comment: Have you verified the content in the database? Also, PLEASE do not use the deprecated `mysql_X` functions, either move to PDO or use `mysqli_X` functions.

Comment: Yes i verified the content. I thought, that this is caused by the content. But this function always returns this result.

Comment: Could you post the `$query` used by your results?

Comment: The Query: "SELECT * FROM speisen"

Comment: Why do you have the `@` sign in-front of `mysql_fetch_assoc()`? It doesn't strike me as a function that triggers any "ignoreable" errors. Does it produce any error on that second entry if you remove it? If so, what?

Comment: I removed the '@'. Nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes please try (it's your code with some debug output and some boilerplate)

```
<?php
$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test', $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));

echo 'mysql_get_client_info: ', mysql_get_client_info(), "\n";
echo 'mysql_get_host_info: ', mysql_get_host_info($mysql), "\n";
echo 'mysql_get_server_info: ', mysql_get_server_info($mysql), "\n";
echo 'mysql_get_proto_info: ', mysql_get_proto_info($mysql), "\n";

setup($mysql);

$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tmpspeisen', $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));
$foo = new Foo($mysql);
var_dump ( $foo->result($query) );

class Foo {
    protected $resourceHandler;

    public function __construct($mysql) {
        $this->resourceHandler = $mysql;
    }

    public function result($query) {
        $result = false;
        if (is_resource($this->resourceHandler)) {
            $result = array();
            while ($tempVar = @mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $result[] = $tempVar;
            }
        }else{
            throw new Exception ('Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank vorhanden!');
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

function setup($mysql) {
    mysql_query('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpspeisen (
            id int auto_increment,
            description varchar(128),
            `date` Date,
            primary key(id)
        )
    ', $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));

    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO tmpspeisen (description, `date`) VALUES
        ('Test', '2012-08-09'), ('Test2', '2012-08-09'), ('test3', '2012-08-10')
    ", $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));
}
```

prints on my machine

```
mysql_get_client_info: mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: b0b3b15c693b7f6aeb3aa66b646fee339f175e39 $
mysql_get_host_info: localhost via TCP/IP
mysql_get_server_info: 5.5.25a
mysql_get_proto_info: 10
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["description"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-09"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["description"]=>
    string(5) "Test2"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-09"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["description"]=>
    string(5) "test3"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-10"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think i got my problem! If i print out the result a bit earlier it's correct. --> mysql_fetch_assoc() works right. So my mistake is at another position.